# How to find the p-value of a t-test using the critical value?

Tags: self-study, t-test, p-value

I keep looking over the lecture and they just seem to skip how they get from the critical value to the p-value, but we need to be able to do this for the exam!

So I've calculated the test statistic $(t) = 0.95669$

$df = 9$

and the critical value of t at $0.05 = 2.26$ (using a 2-tailed 0.05 t distribution table).

Using R, I can see that the p-value is $0.36361$.

How do I calculate this by hand?

Answer (score 1):

You will typically be given a table in which you can look those values up. An example of such a table can be found on the [wikipedia page for the t-distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution). More importantly you will probably be given the table that is printed at the end of the textbook that you are using in your course. Look at that and familiarize yourself with its layout.

Comment: To add to Maarten's response, your textbook will also describe how to use the tables that he mentioned above.